# Is there a way to use login/password of login account to reuse in a playbook?

Tags: rundeck

I have created a job with 2 options for the user writes his login/password. This credentials will be used later in a playbook as extra-variables.

But all this credentials are readable in logs !!!

How to workaround that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Mask Password" Log filter in your inline-playbook or your playbook steps (also, for any Rundeck step), you can check the documentation [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/log-filters/mask-passwords.html). I did a Job Definition example that works:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='opt1' secure='true' value='12345' valueExposed='true' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>2c9b3903-a545-4dbd-aeac-578889dbb611</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>name: 192.168.33.20</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <node-step-plugin type='com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsiblePlaybookInlineWorkflowNodeStep'>
          <configuration>
            <entry key='ansible-base-dir-path' value='/home/user/' />
            <entry key='ansible-become' value='false' />
            <entry key='ansible-playbook-inline' value='---&#10;# This playbook prints a simple debug message&#10;- name: Echo &#10;  hosts: all&#10;  connection: local&#10;&#10;  tasks:&#10;  - name: Print debug message&#10;    debug:&#10;      msg: ${option.opt1}' />
            <entry key='ansible-ssh-passphrase-option' value='option.password' />
            <entry key='ansible-ssh-use-agent' value='false' />
          </configuration>
        </node-step-plugin>
        <plugins>
          <LogFilter type='LogFilter:mask-passwords'>
            <config>
              <color>red</color>
              <replacement>[SECURE]</replacement>
            </config>
          </LogFilter>
        </plugins>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>2c9b3903-a545-4dbd-aeac-578889dbb611</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Comment: thank you very much @MegaDrive68k. I missed that feature.